# How to bind a keypress to HTML document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a press any key page, so that when a key is pressed, it will trigger my animations to start and therefore assemble the page (for example, a key is pressed, and my box slides out from the left etc... Preferably having multiple elements triggered). Whether it uses jQuery or javascript doesn't matter.. I asked this question before but couldn't get helpful answers. I haven't got any code to show. Any examples are welcome.

Comment: Search onkeypress and similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickest way sonce you brought up jQuery:

```
$("#target").on ("keyup", function () {
    //animations
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: This worked. Have to click the document first, but that's no big deal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Example HTML would be,

```
<button>Click me</button>
```

### JavaScript

```
<button onkeypress="function1()"></button>
```

Then in the JS script

```
function function1 () {
  // function.
}
```

### jQuery

```
$('button').keypress(function () {
   // function.
}
```

#### Binding

```
$('button').bind('keypress', function () {
   // function.
});
```

These are the main examples, you can Google for more/should've googled first.

Answer (score 0):

You make an event listener for a page keypress and then you remove the event and call your function.
Code :

```
var press_any_key  = {
    init : function( callback ){
        this.callback = callback;
        document.body.addEventListener('keypress', press_any_key.event);
    },
    event : function(){
        document.body.removeEventListener('keypress', press_any_key.event);
        press_any_key.callback();
    }
}


press_any_key.init( loadThePage );

function loadThePage(){
    alert('This works.');
}
```

Call the functions you need from the 'loadThePage' function